# excel - remove rows where duplicate entry in field exists

Tags: excel, vba

is it possible to with a formula or vba to delete an entire row where some string exists in a field

for example, if A1 has "string1" and A234 has "string1" then i want to keep only 1 of that row

Comment: Before I look for an answer for macros, you specifically want a macro? Coz in Excel 2010 (and the one before it I believe), you can go to the Data tab and click on "Remove Duplicates" that lets you select the column in which the values shouldn't duplicate. You still want a macro for that?

Comment: @beemer wow what a treasure!!!!!!!!!!! thank u so much

Comment: @Beemer yes, Office 2007 also has this feature.  There is also a way to do it with formulas and a filter, and I still see people do it that way today, despite me pointing out the new feature... hard to break old habits eh?

Comment: @i am a girl; that was exactly my feeling when I found out about it the first time, too! Anytime.

Comment: @beemer please make that into an answer so that i can mark it right

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had a hunch that you're just looking to delete rows without necessarily making a macro. 
My solution to this one-time issue is to manually use the Remove Duplicates feature of Excel 2007+ under the Data tab; some people overlook this quick-and-painless feature.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a post that contains a function you are looking for:

- http://www.cpearson.com/excel/deleting.htm

There are multiple functions here, take a look at `DeleteDuplicateRows`.

You can find another one here:

- http://www.ozgrid.com/forum/showthread.php?t=22782&page=1

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to create a distinct list...
Select the data you want, and in the Filter section go Filter => Advanced. Then select Copy to new location, distinct records only.

That will copy a distinct list of the selected records to your chosen location